# Python 3 function parameters validation

Tags: python

What is wrong? First parameter - num_of_edges I need int type and others float.

```
import math
def polygon(num_of_edges, radius, startx, starty, turn_angle):
        try:
            num_of_edges = int(num_of_edges)
            radius = float(radius)
            startx = float(startx)
            starty = float(starty)
            turn_angle = float(turn_angle)
        except ValueError:
            print("All parameters not corect!")
        else:
            turn_angle = 90 - turn_angle 
            pirmais_angle = math.radians(turn_angle)
            points = []
            for i in range(num_of_edges):
                angle = 2*math.pi*(-i)/num_of_edges+pirmais_angle 
                x = math.cos(angle)*radius+startx
                y = math.sin(angle)*radius+starty
                points.append((x, y))
            return points
```

Comment: How should we know what is wrong? You haven't told us what happens when you try, or what errors you get.

Comment: [Well..](http://images.liveluvcreate.com/create/w/whats_wrong_nothing_everything-274678.jpg)

Comment: polygon(a,3,e,0,0) if function call like that, first and 3rd parameter is not correct, but print("All parameters not corect!") that line don't work

Comment: I run the code with some inputs, and it gives output.  If there's a problem, please say what the input is you use and what the output is you get, and what the output is you expect to get.

Comment: What is the traceback of error? Is there any error?

Answer (score -1):

When I run with the suggested input, I get

```
polygon(a,3,e,0,0)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

The problem here is that it's not even getting into your function.  Python already knows that `a` is undefined and it's refusing to even call polygon.  So the test in polygon isn't even attempted.

If it were able to get into the function, you'd still get a `NameError`, not a `ValueError`.  So your `except` has the wrong test.

Note: you aren't guaranteed to get a particular error type for all bad input.  For exmaple `float(1+1j)`  (float of a complex number) raises a `TypeError`.